# Python script restarts itself. Why?

Tags: python, asynchronous, process, scheduled-tasks, apscheduler

I have a Python script that runs for around 16 hours a day and it schedules multiple specific jobs at specific times of the day. Everyday whenever this script is being used, usually after running for a few hours (maybe 7 hours) it all of sudden starts a second instance of itself and schedules all the jobs for a second time, meaning that every single job gets executed two times consecutively.

I am using Python 3.6.3, apscheduler, sqlalchemy and few other libraries. I was thinking that maybe my misunderstanding of BackgroundScheduler may be the problem or the while clause at the end of the following code sample:

Here is a simplified code sample.

```
import time
from datetime import datetime, timedelta, date

import telepot
from apscheduler.schedulers.background import BackgroundScheduler

from sqlalchemy import create_engine, asc
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker

... (code omitted for readability)

EDIT:(addition of jobA method)

def jobA(Session, var):
     print("job A")

     session = Session()
     entity = session.query(Entity).filter(...).first()
     try:
          all = method(entity,...)
    except:
        print("Exception was thrown")
        session.commit()
        session.close()
        return []

     session.commit()
     session.close()
     return all

def jobB(...):
    ... 
def jobC(...):
    ...

if __name__ == "__main__":
ENGINE = create_engine(DB)
Session = sessionmaker(bind=ENGINE)

Loggers.http_console_debug()

   ...
TelegramBot = telepot.Bot(Constants.BOT_TOKEN)
TelegramBot.sendMessage(chat_id=Constants.CHAT_ID, text="Started\n")


   ...
try:
    scheduler = BackgroundScheduler(use_reloader=False)
    scheduler.start()

    i = 1
    for var in data:
        i += 1
        ...

        start_date_time = datetime.combine(var.date, var.time)
        #
        scheduler.add_job(jobA, 'date', 
                          run_date=start_date_time - timedelta(minutes=15), args=[Session, var])
        scheduler.add_job(jobB, 'date', 
                          run_date=start_date_time - timedelta(minutes=10), args=[Session, var])

        scheduler.add_job(jobC, 'date',
                          run_date=start_date_time - timedelta(minutes=3), args=[Session, var])

        scheduler.add_job(jobD, 'date',
                          run_date=start_date_time + timedelta(minutes=11), args=[Session, var])

    print(scheduler.get_jobs())
except:
    print("Exception has been thrown")


session.commit()
session.close()


while True:
    time.sleep(1)
    sys.stdout.flush()
```

This happens both when I run it from command line prompt or from pycharm. When running pgrep it has interesting results.:

```
pgrep python
```

After the program has been started, it returns a single process number. However after a few hours it returns two separate processes. Meaning that the Python script is now running twice. With no input from anybody.

In short, my Python script starts for second time for no reason while it is running and I am trying to figure out how to prevent this from happening, and altering it so that the script runs only once in the period of time and schedules its jobs only once.

Thank you so much.

EDIT: Honestly, I don't know what causes this script to start on it's own second time in a separate process. I found this as an example of use for apscheduler and I am looking into fixing this bug of restarting itself.

Here is a link that I used as inspiration for using APScheduler.(Date-based scheduler)
https://pythonadventures.wordpress.com/2013/08/06/apscheduler-examples/

Comment: What is the `while True:` loop at the bottom for? That loop will never break and the script will never terminate but it's also doing nothing productive that I can see.

Comment: Are you thinking that the scheduler should "understand" that the process is already running and not start another?  What caused the script to "start on it's own"  while the other is running?  It seems you're missing a semaphore in the scheduler...

Comment: @DDeMartini 
I really don't know what is causing it to start on it's own again mid-day. I found this script as an example for apscheduler background scheduler so I'll probably look into implementing semaphore.

Comment: Are `jobA`, `jobB` etc. separate scripts, or is one of them this script?

Comment: @JohnGordon, they are methods and to be honest they are inside this same file.

Comment: @DDeMartini
Really the only problem is that the script starts second time mid-day. If it did not start again, that would solve the problem. Also if it understood the jobs were already scheduled that would solve it too with maybe unnecessary complexity.

Comment: @dev85  I used be be a job scheduler for HP "back in the day" so I feel your pain.  I think the solution is a semaphore / process that will detect if a job is currently running and either put into a pending/delayed state (there are pitfalls there, you could end up with days or weeks of backlog),  or simply skip it until the current job completes.. but there needs to be monitors on that as well, because if the main job hangs (doesn't die) all processing will be blocked.  I'm not familiar with the scheduling system you're using, so I'm not sure I offer much more than best practice suggestions.

Comment: @DDeMartini
Thanks that should solve the problem that if there is such process running do not schedule again. 

It's really just that python starts itself again and I have no idea why. :D

Comment: @dev85 What OS?  There might be a crontab setup somewhere on the user or at the root level that is running the job at certain times.  Really could be caused by anything, some things even re-schedule themselves with 'at' commands (scary stuff).   You could also look at the process stack for one of the jobs that is being launched 'automagically', get it's parent ID and see if that leads you to the origin.

Comment: @DDeMartini it is Linux xubuntu 17.10 and python is 3.6.3 from anaconda virtual environment.I ll try to follow your advice. How do one inspects a process stack is what I m wondering.

Comment: @dev85  there are a couple of ways to do that.  One is the utility  'top'   which shows processes and a fair number of metrics such as memory, CPU, parent processes etc.   You man also use   'ps'     you might try   'ps -ealf | grep <process_name>'  and see how many are running, whom their parent pid (process ID) and then grep for that in the ps output.. that might lead you to whom forked / launched the process.  You might find crond or something else.